# Using ESRI Javascript 4.0 API with Require JS

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am running into some issues when switching my application from the Beta 3 version of the 4.0 ArcGIS Javascript API to the new release of the 4.0 Javascript API.

I had a working map when using the beta3 version of the 4.0 javascript API and had configured Require JS to load the modules correctly with the beta 3 version like this

```
 requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/App/",
    paths: {
        "text": "/Scripts/text",
        "moment": "/Scripts/moment",
        "durandal": "/Scripts/durandal",
        "plugins": "/Scripts/durandal/plugins",
        "transitions": "/Scripts/durandal/transitions",
        "esri": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0beta3/esri",
        "dojo": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0beta3/dojo",
        "dojox": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0beta3/dojox",
        "dijit": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0beta3/dijit",
    },
});
```

However once i switch from 4.0beta3 to just 4.0

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/App/",
    paths: {
        "text": "/Scripts/text",
        "moment": "/Scripts/moment",
        "durandal": "/Scripts/durandal",
        "plugins": "/Scripts/durandal/plugins",
        "transitions": "/Scripts/durandal/transitions",
        "esri": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri",
        "dojo": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojo",
        "dojox": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojox",
        "dijit": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dijit",
    },
});
```

I get an error while trying to load the map where it is trying to load this script and it gives a 404

```
http://localhost:17654/Scripts/moment/moment.js
```

I believe it is attempting to load this script because the ESRI Api uses its own moment plugin and since i've already defined what moment is, its attempting to look at localhost instead of loading the esri module.

I've tried a few different configurations with require and with this i can get the page to load with no javascript errors however no map shows up

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/App/",
    paths: {
        "text": "/Scripts/text",
        "moment": "/Scripts/moment",
        "durandal": "/Scripts/durandal",
        "plugins": "/Scripts/durandal/plugins",
        "transitions": "/Scripts/durandal/transitions",
        "esri": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri",
        "dojo": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojo",
        "dojox": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojox",
        "dijit": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dijit",
    },
    map: {
        "*": {
            "moment/moment": "moment"
        }
    }
});
```

I know the javascript API uses its own version of dojo which is supposed to handle the module loading so mixing it in with require js might not even be possible but since it was working fine with the beta3 i'm hoping to find a way to get this moment plugin to load properly and have the map work using require js.

Does anyone have any experience with getting these two to work together? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be able to work with requirejs, however is there a particular reason you are using it instead of esri's AMD loader that comes down with their API?  Using theirs should make things generally easier but you will probably run into the same issues using their loader since esri has already defined the package/alias for moment.  One thing you may be able to try is naming it differently for your paths.  Something like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "/App/",
  paths: {
    "text": "/Scripts/text",
    "local-moment": "/Scripts/moment",
    "durandal": "/Scripts/durandal",
    "plugins": "/Scripts/durandal/plugins",
    "transitions": "/Scripts/durandal/transitions",
    "esri": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri",
    "dojo": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojo",
    "dojox": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojox",
    "dijit": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/dijit",
  },
});
```

This way esri can still require their `moment` and you could require your `local-moment`.

Comment: We are using require JS instead of the esri AMD loader because we are utilizing Durandal as a Single Page Application framework which depends on require js instead of dojo.

Comment: Ahh ok cool, well they shouldn't really have an issue working together as long as the configuration is solid

Comment: I've updated the configuration to this as you suggested, with one minor tweak. 

i added one more path `"moment/moment" : "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/moment/moment"`

 And now the page actually loads without the moment.js error however the map no longer shows up.  Same code as before with the beta3 version.

Comment: Does it throw any errors or is it just blank?  And if you leave out the last path for `moment/moment` and try the exact configuration above does that work at all? Sounds like you may be close but just need to tweak the config a little bit.  I would try removing the path config for `moment/moment` first, if that fails then try changing `"moment/moment": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/moment/moment"` to `"moment": "//js.arcgis.com/4.0/moment/moment"`.

Answer (score -3):

I think if you'll have in your folder Scripts/moment/ moment.js file everything would be fine.